# If $K$ and $K'$ are compact such that $K$ is contained in interior of $K'$, then show that $D_K$ is nowhere dense in $D_{K'}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $D_K$ be the space of all smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are compactly supported in $K$ for a compact $K$. If $K$ and $K'$ are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $K$ is contained in the interior of $K'$, then show that $D_K$ is nowhere dense in $D_{K'}$.

It's an old qual problem and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: consider for example the $L^2(K),L^2(K')$ norms. then for a fixed $u \in D_{K'}$, what is $\inf_{v \in D_K} \|u - v\|_{L^2(D_{K'})}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 is it $\||u||_{L^2(K'/K)}$?

Comment: $D_K$ is a proper closed subspace of $D_{K'}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer would I then need to show that $D_K$ has empty interior to complete the proof?

Comment: If you can't just cite the fact that a proper subspace of a topological vector space always has empty interior, then you indeed need to prove that to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is trivially properly contained in $\mathring{K^\prime}$, we can find $x_0\in\mathring{K^\prime}$ and some $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(x_0)\subset(\mathring{K^\prime}\setminus K)\subset (K^\prime\setminus K)$.

Then
$$f(x) := \begin{cases}e^{1/\left(\delta^2-\|x-x_0\|^2\right)} & \|x-x_0\|<\delta\\ 0 & \|x-x_0\|\geq\delta\end{cases}$$
is commonly used as a smooth function which vanishes outside $B_\delta(x_0)$.

Note that $\epsilon f\in D_{K^\prime}\setminus D_K$ is arbitrarily small (in the $\infty$ norm, which I presume is used here, but also in any other norm, at least).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this is showing that the complement  $D_{K'}\setminus D_K$ contains a open dense subset?

Comment: @dezdichado we can get arbitrarily close to every $g\in \overline{D_K}$ by $g+\epsilon f$ which are isolated from $D_K$.